Unhandled Exception: Failed host lookup: 'https:myexampleapi.com'
I have an API that gives me data each time I send POST request with 2 keys: u & pw.
The Data Structure of API provides is like this below:
{
    "status": "done",
    "coins": 123456,
}

Also this is an Stateful Widget I Created.
It's a button with some customized Attributes.
class LigoButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final VoidCallback ontap;

  const LigoButton({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.width,
    required this.height,
    required this.ontap,
  });

  @override
  State<LigoButton> createState() => _LigoButtonState();
}

class _LigoButtonState extends State<LigoButton> {
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: widget.width,
      height: widget.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        gradient: const LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          colors: <Color>[
            Color(0xffFEAC5D),
            Color(0xffF43469),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () async {
            if (isLoading) return;

            setState(() {
              isLoading = true;
            });

            widget.ontap();

            await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
            });
          },
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          child: Center(
            child: isLoading
                ? const SizedBox(
                    width: 20.0,
                    height: 20.0,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )
                : Text(
                    widget.text.tr,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 17.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Lalezar',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I used my Widget on the main Code and I'm sending the POST request like this below:
LigoButton(
                      text: 'checkDepository',
                      width: 120.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      ontap: () async {
                        var adminID = adminIDController.text;
                        var adminPassword = adminPasswordController.text;

                        final response = await http.post(
                          Uri.parse("https://myexampleapi.com"),
                          headers: <String, String>{
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                          },
                          body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
                            'u': adminID,
                            'pw': adminPassword,
                          }),
                        );

                        var coins = jsonDecode(response.body);

                        LigoStatus.status = response.statusCode == StatusCode.OK
                            ? 'OK'
                            : 'ERROR';

                        setState(
                          () {
                            totalCoinContainer = Container(
                              width: 200.0,
                              height: 50.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  width: 1.5,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  coins['coins'],
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                    fontFamily: 'Lalezar',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),

And everytime I click on my LigoButton Widget it gives me this Error.
E/flutter ( 6068): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Failed host lookup: 'myexampleapi.com'

I would be thankful if you provide me an answer or sth that can help me with this.

did you try with an IP address?
